# Referencing cell values on DataGridView from another form

Tags: vb.net

This is bugging me.  I have a "main" form named frmMain with a DataGridView object named objDataGrid.

When a user double clicks on a row or clicks another button, I hide the main form, open a new form and want to reference the values in the row selected by the user but I keep getting an error when I try to access some, but not all, of the datagridview's properties.

For example here is the code that opens the form:

```
    On Error Resume Next

    Me.Hide()
    frmGenerate.Show()
```

In the frmGenerate's load event I do the following:

```
    Dim frmMain As frmMain = Nothing
    frmMain = New frmMain
```

Any time I try to grab a value from the grid I get various errors.

```
    frmMain.objDataGrid.Item(1, 2).Value
    frmMain.objDataGrid.Rows(2).Cells(4).Value
    frmMain.objDataGrid.SelectedRows(0).Index
    frmMain.objDataGrid.Item(1, frmMain.objDataGrid.SelectedRows(0).Index).Value
```

These return index out of range errors even though I know for sure the indexes are correct.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you creating a new instance of frmMain?  You need to refer to the existing one where they've selected a row.

You could pass just the row of the datagrid or PK field values instead of referencing the other form.